# How to reverse the order of values in one column in a dataframe grouped by another column?

Tags: r, sorting, group-by, reverse

Given the following toy data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                 B = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

This data frame consists of 2 columns of which both columns are sorted ascending.

The desired result is the same data frame, but with reversed values for column 'B' for each group specified by the values in column 'A':

```
> df
   A B
1  A 3
2  A 2
3  A 1
4  B 2
5  B 1
6  C 5
7  C 4
8  C 3
9  C 2
10 C 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ave` if you are with base R:

```
df <- within(df,B <- ave(B,A,FUN = function(x) sort(x,decreasing = TRUE)))
```

which gives

```
> df
   A B
1  A 3
2  A 2
3  A 1
4  B 2
5  B 1
6  C 5
7  C 4
8  C 3
9  C 2
10 C 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case column 'B' is numeric, therefore the use of the `order` function with a minus sign in front of `df$B` works

```
df$B <- df$B[order(df$A, -df$B)]
```

More general use is with the function `xtfrm` in case column 'B' is not numeric in other similar cases:

```
df$B <- df$B[order(df$A, -xtfrm(df$B))]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, tidy way:

```
df %>% arrange(A, desc(B))
```

output as

```
   A B
1  A 3
2  A 2
3  A 1
4  B 2
5  B 1
6  C 5
7  C 4
8  C 3
9  C 2
10 C 1
```